# Modifying which Wordpress categories are displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, categories

I'm building a bespoke Wordpress theme for a periodical. I have a category set up that basically marks an article as "featured," making them appear on the homepage. I'd like for this category to not appear when browsing the site, however, as it's meant for the magazine's staff to be able to control what's on the homepage, rather than be used as a tool for user's to search with.

Since the_category(); will return all categories, I need help building a php loop that will display categories while skipping this one. A post will only ever have one category, unless this second one is applied. I also think building a function that could be referenced several times across the site would be the most efficient way of handling this.

If there's an even simpler method to reach the same outcome, feel free to point that out as well. I'd just like to keep my plugin dependencies minimal. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research into my options for developing with Wordpress, I've found that using a custom post type will work far better than filing these posts under a category. Apologies for the confusing post.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first have to find the id of the "featured" category.

Then find the php pages where the categories are displayed (I know they are in single.php for instance).

Once you've done that, just add a if/else statement to display categories only if the category isn't "featured":

```
<?php 
    if(in_category('idOfFeaturedCategory')){} // For this category, do not echo anything

    else {?>
        <p>Catégorie(s) : <strong><?php the_category(','); ?></strong></p> <!-- echo all the others categories -->
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! But I'm a little confused as how to I could apply this since it still uses the_category(). I'd still like to display the category of every article, even featured ones, I'd just like to hide the "featured" category from view. The site is for a magazine, and they don't have a section titled "featured," so I'm trying to hide that one category from view, if that makes more sense.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what the code I provided does: it displays all the posts, but hides the category field only for the category id in the if statement. But it seems like you've found another way, good for you :)